# Knockout date validation not working correctly

Tags: javascript, validation, date, knockout.js, durandal

I need to validate date in localized format (SK) and it is not possible with knockout validation.

I am using:
Durandal 1.2.0
Knockout 2.3.0
Knockout validation https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation

I need something like this to be working:

```
var newStartDate = ko.observable()
.extend({ 
required: { message: 'Start date is required.' }, 
date: true, 
formattedDate: { format: 'ddMMyyyy', delimiter: '.' } 
});
```

Then if I call newStartDate.isValid() I get these results:

```
newStartDate("");
false (OK)

newStartDate("test");
false (OK)

newStartDate("2013-02-02");
true (Bad)

newStartDate("2.2.2013");
false (Bad)
```

The results should be:

```
newStartDate("2013-02-02");
false

newStartDate("2.2.2013)"; // or "2. 2. 2013"
true
```

I have some solution with custom validation inside of extend function, but that is not what I want.
I want to have block above working, it's also shorter.

Comment: Where does the formattedDate validation rule come from? I don't see it anywhere in the list of built-in or user-contributed custom rules in the Knockout-Validation docs.

Comment: I found it here, but I am not 100% sure if its in my version, https://github.com/neildonkin/Knockout-Validation/commit/25d132f1ec154118667d276c6c4a0dab5e94758b

Answer (score 13):

A little late by why not...
The date rule does seem a bit too permissive for my uses as well.  If you like moment but want something cleaner for the caller, add your rule to the validation.rules object:

```
ko.validation.rules['simpleDate'] = {
    validator: function (val, validate) {
        return ko.validation.utils.isEmptyVal(val) || moment(val, 'MM/DD/YYYY').isValid();
    },
    message: 'Invalid date'
};
```

And then use it like:

```
var someDate= ko.observable().extend({ simpleDate: true });
```

Comment: [vote up] Thanks, I've extended your answer with the format being passed in so that it can be reused elsewhere.

Comment: I've added it to the ko validation wiki User Contributed Rules... https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/User-Contributed-Rules

Answer (score 2):

Very late for this, but just want to share my updates on @ChoptimusPrime's answer. Not hard-coding the format:

```
ko.validation.rules['dateAndFormat'] = {
    validator: function (val, format) {
        return ko.validation.utils.isEmptyVal(val) || moment(val, format).isValid();
    },
    message: 'Please provide a valid date.'
};
ko.validation.registerExtenders();
```

Answer (score 1):

The only working solution I have for now is below.
The problem with this validator is that it also validates default(EN) date format as valid, so I have to add a IF to return this as invalid date format.

`var dateValidator = function (val) {
            if (!val)
                return false;
            if (moment(val, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm').isValid()) {
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        };`

var startDate = ko.observable().extend({ validation: { validator: dateValidator, message: 'Start of task is not in correct format.' } });

Comment: Downvoted, this aint even using knockout validation rules. It might work, but it's definatly not the way to go with KOJS.