# Html5 datetime-local control shows incomplete date

Tags: html, validation, datetime, knockout.js

I'm new to HTML5 and Knockout.js  I am facing an issue in datetime-local control.

Here is the HTML datetime-control I'm using

```
<script type="text/html" id="DATE.template">
    <input type="datetime-local" data-bind="value: Prompt.CurrentValue, enable: Prompt.IsEnabled, valueUpdate: 'input'" />
</script>
```

Here is the Save button and it's  binded to savecommand to javascript file.

```
<div class="buttons-wrapper">
              <button class="button save-idoc-button" data-bind="command: SaveIdocCommand, activity:SaveIdocCommand.isExecuting">Save</button>
              <button class="button cancel-save-button" data-bind="command: CancelIdocCommand, activity:CancelIdocCommand.isExecuting">Cancel</button>
           </div>
```

When I enter the date without entering any time, date is being passed null on SAVE. I understand it's a incomplete date, hence the browser considers it a invalid date, but the entered date is not saved. The Selected date is binded to Prompt.CurrentValue; When user enters an incomplete date (without time), prompt.currentvalue is null, and I get a tooltip message on the datetime control that "Please enter a valid date or date entered is incomplete". (browser validates and provides i think)

What is the best approach to take?
a. should we need to provide the custom validation and disable the SAVE button, until the datetime-local control has a valid value. If so, how we can achieve in html5/knockout.js?

b. Is there a way to disable the browser validation of datetime-local control, so that the date can be passed even though time is not entered.? (I tried with using "novalidation", but it didn't work)

c. any other better approach?

EDIT:

Here is the computed observable for validation in viewmodel; Prompt.CurrentValue is the value to binded to UI controls. When it's date control, this validationerror doesn't work.

```
> hasValidationErrors = ko.computed(function () {
>                     //loop through fields and filter out fields that are set up with validation and has invalid data.
>                     var invalidFieldsArray=ko.utils.arrayFilter(fields(), function (field) {
>                         return !_.isUndefined(field.Prompt) && !_.isNull(field.Prompt) 
>                                   && (
>                                           ((_.has(field.Prompt.CurrentValue,"isValid"))&&!field.Prompt.CurrentValue.isValid())
> 
>                                           || 
>                                           ((_.has(field.Prompt.AdditionalData, "isValid")) && !field.Prompt.AdditionalData.isValid())
>                                       );
>                     });
>                     return invalidFieldsArray.length > 0;;
>                 })
```

,

this selected datetime-local value is not binded (to the corresponding viewmodel: Prompt.CurrentValue),until the user selects the date and enters the full time ... I understand browser does this validation for this control. how can computed observable recognize this invalidity of date control ? (as value is not passed until the value is valid)

Comment: can you post some example code snippets that demonstrate the issue?

Comment: posted the code for datetime control..

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things - if you are submitting the form to a server your `<input`needs a name attribute to save properly. And you can preset it to a current value if you want e.g. `<input name="date" etc`.

You need to show your viewModel if you want help with that.

Re validation - a simple Google search shows this validation suite https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation

However, in Javascript anything to do with dates (date validation, date presentation, date tranformation) you should be using Moment.js

EDIT:

Will have a look at your code above when I get a chance.  Please note value is not a good binding for date inputs.  I suggest you change

```
data-bind="value: Prompt.CurrentValue, enable: Prompt.IsEnabled, valueUpdate: 'input'"
```

to

```
data-bind="textInput: Prompt.CurrentValue, enable: Prompt.IsEnabled"
```

EDIT 2:

OK, so date-time is NOT supported in **ANY** version of Firefox, IE, or Safari - it is a pure text input.

Check out https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Native-Rules and [Knockout date validation not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405186/knockout-date-validation-not-working-correctly), but I think it is best to switch to moment.js (isValid()) and stick to a specifically formatted date string or use a jquery style popup calendar.

Comment: We are using knockout.js and notice that general validations are in place for all the properties (using computed observable) in the view model using knockout library. But this seelcted datetime-local value is not binded (to the corresponding viewmodel valuel),until the user selects the date and enters the full time ... I  understand browser does this validation for this control. how can computed observable recognize this invalidity of date control ? (as value is not passed until the value is valid)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to disable the browser validation of datetime-local control, so that the date can be passed even though time is not entered

If possible, can you use a combination of `<input type="date">` and `<input type="time">` instead? (and use the `textInput` binding while you're at it)